# Why does this code output is 'thread:Thread..' ,not 'runnable:Thread..'?

Tags: java-threads

I have a simple thread test code snippet,its pseudo code like this `new Thread(new Runnable(){...implement run method....}){...override run method...}.start();`. my problem is why does this code output is 'thread:Thread..' ,not  'runnable:Thread..'?here is the complete code.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){//1 annonymous class implement Runnable interface
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                System.out.println("runnable:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }){
            public void run() {//2 annonymous class extends Thread class 
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            };
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Thread`'s `run` method will delegate to the `Runnable` you supplied in the constructor.

However, you overrode the `run` method in your (anonymous) subclass of `Thread` to do something else.